# Can't wrrite Text on a Div, on a Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to write text on a div that comes from this code:

```
    var resume = document.createElement("div");
            resume.style.position = "fixed";
            resume.style.height = 0.1*canvas.height + "px";
            resume.style.width = 0.4*canvas.width + "px";
            resume.style.bottom = 0.75*canvas.height + "px";
            resume.style.left = 0.3*canvas.width + "px";
            resume.style.backgroundColor = "Black";
            resume.style.opacity = "0.8";
            resume.textAlign = "center";
            resume.color = "White";
            resume.p = "efege";
            document.body.appendChild(resume);
```

and is situated on this canvas

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvy");

    var b = canvas.getContext("2d");

    b.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

    b.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

why isn't my text showing up?
How would I get text to appear using resume.(some command here)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured Out I just needed to create another element and appendChild it to the Div.
In case anyone wanted to know.
Heres the code

```
    var x = document.createElement("SPAN");
            resume.appendChild(x);
            x.textContent = "anytext";
```